# Too much space below equation in a footnote

Tags: spacing, equations, footnotes, footer, vertical-spacing

I'm getting too much space below an equation placed into a footnote, when there's no text below the equation.  How can I remove that extra space?  Here's a MWE that shows the trouble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Blabla\footnote{Blablabla:
    \begin{equation*}
        y(x) = x^2.
    \end{equation*}
Some blablabla.}

Blabla\footnote{Blablabla:
    \begin{equation*}
        y(x) = x^2.
    \end{equation*}
}

\end{document}
```

Here's a preview:

[image]

I need to remove that extra space (shown in red in the preview picture).  How can I tell LaTeX to never add some extra space between the last equation displayed in a footnote and the margin, if there's no text below it?

Comment: Not a solution, but a suggestion on writing style. Some may argue that writing display formulas in footnotes is generally a bad idea (if the formula is important, why stuck it inside a footnote; and if it is not important, why not just use inline math in footnote). You could also write a phrase or two following the formula, so the footnote ends with a sentence rather than a display.

Comment: @RuixiZhang, there are cases for which it would be inapropriate to display the equation in the main text, since it's not about the main subject.  I then have to write a footnote for it instead.  In the footnote, I usually write some text below the displayed equation.  But there are a few cases where the footnote ends with the displayed equation (a list of few small equations, for example).  Then, I get that extra space that I want to remove to save space or for other reasons (the extra space is ugly!  Especially if there's a second footnote after it).

Comment: can't you use an inline display `$y(x)=x^2$` ? a displayed formula in a footnote seems pretty strange to me. (otherwise set `\belowdisplayskip=0pt` before the formula

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, the displayed equation is pretty big for inline.  Example : integral or large fractions...

Comment: don't put it in a footnote then:-) but setting \belowdisplayskip and \belowdisplayshortskip  to 0pt will probably do what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have to put it in a footnote!  It's not about the main subject in the main text, but I need to show it as a connex subject for reference.  There are frequent cases like this in physics!

Comment: ah physics, in mathematics we basically never use a footnote except in really  exceptional cases.

Comment: In physics, exceptional cases are the norm!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, your solution works.  But what should be the best way to use it, from my MWE above?  Should I put **\belowdisplayskip=0pt** just before the displayed equation (in the footnote)?  And would it affect the rest of the text and other footnotes after that one, or it only has a local effect?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You can set the display skips to 0 or for even tighter spacing use an inline math set using `\displaystyle`

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\let\zzzfootnotesize\footnotesize
\def\newfootnotesize{%
\zzzfootnotesize
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=\abovedisplayskip
\abovedisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayskip
\belowdisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayskip
}
\renewcommand\footnotesize{\protect\newfootnotesize}

\begin{document}

Blabla\footnote{Blablabla:
    \begin{equation*}
        y(x) = x^2.
    \end{equation*}
Some blablabla.}

Blabla\footnote{Blablabla:
    \begin{equation*}
        y(x) = x^2.
    \end{equation*}
}

\end{document}
```

or...

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{nccmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}



\begin{document}

Blabla\footnote{Blablabla:\\
    \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
        y(x) = x^2.
    $}\\
Some blablabla.}

Blabla\footnote{Blablabla:\\
    \makebox[\linewidth]{$\displaystyle
        y(x) = x^2.
    $}
}

\end{document}
```